# Particles Not Emitting Smoke

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

I am using 2.83a and I am trying to create smoke from a chimney stack of a steam locomotive.

The plan is/was to animate the domain along with the ground surroundings - long story.

I have been tearing my hair out trying to find the right settings for the smoke emitter and domain - I would have ideally liked a small amount of fire and a generous amount of smoke, but I cannot seem to prevent the emitter from spewing it in all directions, any setting less than 1.0 from the surface of the emitter results in no smoke.

A more satisfactory way to animate the smoke is to use the emitter to emit particles. I've successfully managed that in the past but I am not sure what I am doing wrong now.

The Emitter is set to emit particles and die out shortly afterwards - it isn't affected by the domain so I have a wind force field. If the particles emit smoke, it will look spot on.

[image]

The domain is set up correctly so far as I can see, buoyancy density is set to -1 so the smoke sinks, heat to 1.5 and vorticity 0.

I've turned off noise for now, turning it on and off made no difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There's something with the new version of Blender that requires you to **Bake Data** in the Smoke domain to start producing smoke.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN6ClIdL8yw&feature=youtu.be

Playing with the fuel value, might help to choose how much fire you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Believe me, I have been playing with the fuel value and every other value - but that is for smoke only. The particle emitter can only do smoke or fire, it can't do "smoke + fire". The problem is the particles are not emitting smoke. I quickly made up this test file and it's not working here either. I did manage to make it work at some stage, but I am blowed if I can figure out what the special case needs to be. When I was going it I was using cycles....and I am currently in Eevee. does that make a difference?

Comment: There's a "smoke+fire" option, when selecting the Flow Type. The quick smoke tool is a handy way to create smoke. In the Physics section of the Smoke Domain there are ways to control the Smoke, Fire and the dissolve rate for the smoke. https://i.imgur.com/6MxaSIt.png

Comment: Also check these out, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RKAL5zST84, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUS8LvST86k,

Comment: Hi thanks Manu - these are great tutorials but they don't really help - I have watched nearly every smoke tutorial there is.

The issue is I wanted constrain my smoke via particles, having re-consulted the manual, I think my issue is the size of my model and how much smoke I want to produce. I wanted to get a lower res idea of what I wanted to do before committing to a long bake. But the problem is I needed a much much higher resolution in order for the smoke simulation to work properly.

Comment: That still leaves the issue of the particle system not emitting smoke, and it may well be the problem there as well. Does anyone know of a resource that shows the effect of smoke physics settings? The manual is a good start, but it does not have scale to judge how these settings work via volume....ie how it should look on a scale of 1m versus how it should on a scale of 10s of meters.

Comment: Blender Tutorial - A Smoking Steam Engine Running Around a Track - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJhtc8te1pw

Comment: Faking Smoke with Particles in Blender Cycles - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tL0G5oOjdtk , This seems to be what you're talking about.

Comment: Yep seen and been through both of these!

I still have had no luck. Even starting from scratch particles will not emit, and I cannot seem to find a way to get the right amount of smoke to be emitted, or to get it affected by force fields. It's incredible...every other aspect about this project is coming together nicely.

Comment: @DrIgnatiusCole Any updates

Comment: Hi Manu, Yes!

The issue was that after setting the Flow source to be the particle emitter, you also have to set the "Particle Settings" which is a non-obvious field that opens below it. Another issue is that I believe "motion blur" needs to be off unless outputting animation. 

I'm planning to write up a complete list of settings and post it for others. Please contribute to it if you can when it goes up.